# Walking subdirectories, converting images into pdf and then merging the pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, merge, os.walk

I have a series of folders inside a parent one. Each folder has several images in .jpg with name in increasing order (00.jpg, 01.jpg...).

I want to convert each image into a pdf with the same name, then merge all the pdfs of each subfolder into a single pdf located in the parent folder and named as the subfolder from which its pdfs come from.

For example, Parent folder ./Random sketches has subdirectories 001 landscapes sketches to 099 urban sketches. So I want to transform the images in each subfolder and then have merged pdfs named 001 landscapes to 099 urban sketches.

I'm fine with the transforming images into pdfs, but I cannot merge them using a loop, even though when I tried the same code on a single subfolder it worked (so without the need to loop through different folders).

I'm having trouble understanding how os.walk() works, so I'm using os.listdir() instead.

This is my current working code:

```
import os
import shutil
import img2pdf
from send2trash import send2trash
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger as merger

parent_folder = '/Users/macbook/Documents/Random sketches/'
os.chdir(parent_folder)
for subfolder in os.listdir(parent_folder):
    if os.path.isdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
        for filename in os.listdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
            if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.JPG')):
                filename_regex = re.compile(r'(\.jpg)|(\.jpeg)', re.IGNORECASE)
                new_name = filename_regex.sub('', filename)
                f = open(parent_folder + subfolder + '/' + new_name + '.pdf', 'wb')
                f.write(img2pdf.convert(parent_folder + subfolder + '/' + filename))
                send2trash(parent_folder + subfolder + '/' + filename)

for subfolder in os.listdir(parent_folder):
    if os.path.isdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
        for file in os.listdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
                if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    merger.append(file)
    merger.write(subfolder +'.pdf')
```

However, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c489b353ceda> in <module>()
     23                 if file.endswith('.pdf'):
     24                     merger.append(file)
---> 25     merger.write(subfolder +'.pdf')

TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileobj'
```

Comment: write method requires a fileobject

Comment: I know, but I thought "subfolder +'.pdf'" should cover it

Comment: no that doesn't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're creating a `PdfFileMerger` object. I don't think you can just import it as `merger`. What happens if you modify your code to:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

...

for subfolder in os.listdir(parent_folder):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    if os.path.isdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
        for file in os.listdir(parent_folder + subfolder):
                if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    merger.append(file)
    merger.write(subfolder +'.pdf')
    merger.close()
```

Comment: It works! i just had to add
parent_folder + subfolder + '/' + before file
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.